# Replace a word in a sentence with words from a list and copying the new sentences in a column

Tags: python, pandas, list, replace

I have a dataframe that contains sentences in one column, specific words I have extracted from the column, and a third column containing a list of synonyms for the words in the second column:

```
data= {"sentences":["I am a student", "she is my friend", "that is the new window"],
       "words": ["student","friend", "window"],
       "synonyms":[["pupil"],["comrade","companion"],["brand new","up-to-date","latest"]]}

df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['sentences', "words","synonyms"])
```

What I would like to do is to create another column with words in sentences being replaced with the words from the synonym columns:

```
print(df["new_col"])
```

Output:

```
I am a pupil

she is my comrade. she is my companion.

this is the brand new window. this is the up-to-date window. this is the latest window.
```

I have tried

```
np.where(df["words"].isin([df["sentences"]), df["sentence"].replace(df["words"].isin([df["sentences"]), df["synonyms"],""  )
```

but it did not give the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a direct dataframe manipulation, but you can still try it :

```
import pandas as pd

data= {"sentences":["I am a student", "she is my friend", "that is the new window"], "words": ["student","friend", "window"], "synonyms":[["pupil"],["comrade","companion"],["brand new","up-to-date","latest"]]}
df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['sentences', "words","synonyms"])

new_col = []
for s in data["sentences"]:
    for index, w in enumerate(data["words"]):
        if w in s:
            a = ". ".join([s.replace(w, syno) for syno in data["synonyms"][index]])
    new_col.append(a)

df["new_col"] = new_col
```

Output :

```
                sentences    words                         synonyms  \
0          I am a student  student                          [pupil]   
1        she is my friend   friend             [comrade, companion]   
2  that is the new window   window  [brand new, up-to-date, latest]

                                             new_col  
0                                       I am a pupil  
1             she is my comrade. she is my companion  
2  that is the new brand new. that is the new up-...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using df.apply and using python map() to iterate over the synonyms:

```
 df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda row: list(map(lambda word: row[0].replace(row[1], word),  row[2])), axis=1).tolist()
```

notice that you have to pass axis=1 on df.apply in order to apply the function to each row of the dataframe:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: thank you for your reply, but it returns a type error. TypeError: ("'map' object is not subscriptable", 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: I guess you are using python3, I've updated the answer, also the new_column is in array shape with the sentences